# How do I avoid a race condition at the end of a GTask that updates a GTK UI?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk3, glib, gdk

I'm building a gtk3 application and was trying to figure out to avoid a race condition at the completion of a `GTask` that updates the UI.

As the function (`data_acq()`) called by the `GTask` is long-running, I have a progress bar that updates (via `gdk_threads_add_timeout(progressBar_timeout_cb)`), but at the end of `data_acq()` I use `gdk_threads_add_idle(progressBar_complete, params)` to set the progress bar to 100%. The issue arises in that the last step of the `GTask` is to automatically call `free_data_acq_data(params)` which frees the pointer to the progress bar, causing a segfault when `progressBar_complete(params)` triggers, if it happens *after* `free_data_acq_data(params)` happens.

It's possible that this issue is entirely due to my abuse of pointers (or some other rookie mistake), but I admit that I'm not seeing how to pass the data in a manner that guarantees 1) that it will be freed after use and 2) that it will not be freed too early. Note that it is possible that the task is cancelled and so I don't want to free the memory in `progressBar_complete()`.

So my question(s): is there a better way to avoid a race condition in this case (or is there another way to structure the code to avoid this issue)? Or is there a mechanism for checking if a `gdk_threads_add_idle()` function has completed so I can tell the memory-freeing function to wait until the `idle` is done?

I tried using a global to track if `progressBar_complete` had run or not, but I couldn't get it to play nicely with the `GTask` because it meant that `free_data_acq_data` never completed (as the thread was never relinquished to `progressBar_complete` to update the global).

For concreteness, here is some example code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct dataAcqParams {
  GtkWidget *progressBar;
  int timeoutID;
  GCancellable *cancellable;
};


void update_progressBar(GtkWidget *progressBar,
                        double fraction)
{
  gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progressBar), fraction);
}

int complete_progressBar(gpointer data)
{
  struct dataAcqParams *params = data;
  GtkWidget *progressBar;
  progressBar = params->progressBar;
  g_source_remove(params->timeoutID); // This turns off automatic progress bar updates
  update_progressBar(progressBar, 1.0);

  return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}

int progressBar_timeout_cb(gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget *progressBar;
  progressBar = params->progressBar;

  double fraction = 0.50; // For brevity
  update_progressBar(progressBar, fraction);

  return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE; // We keep calling this until we cancel it...
}

void free_data_acq_data(void *data)
{
  struct dataAcqParams *params = data;
  g_free(params);
}

int data_acq(struct dataAcqParams *data)
{
  struct dataAcqParams *params = data;

  g_print("Performing a measurement...\n");
  g_usleep(10e5); // Some long computation, can be cancelled
    
  gdk_threads_add_idle(complete_progressBar, params); // Race condition starts here
  g_usleep(500000); // Delay to prevent race condition, surely there is a better way?

  return 0;
}

static void data_acq_cb(GTask    *task,
                        gpointer source_object,
                        gpointer task_data,
                        GCancellable *cancellable)
{
  struct dataAcqParams *params = task_data;
  int retval;

  // Handle Cancellation:
  if(g_task_return_error_if_cancelled(task))
  {
    return;
  }

  retval = data_acq(params);

  g_task_return_int(task, retval);
}

void start_data_acq_async(gpointer            data,
                          GCancellable       *cancellable,
                          GAsyncReadyCallback callback,
                          gpointer            user_data)
{

  GTask *task = NULL;
  struct dataAcqParams *params;
  params = (struct dataAcqParams *) data;

  // Error if this is badly formatted:
  g_return_if_fail(cancellable == NULL | G_IS_CANCELLABLE(cancellable));

  task = g_task_new(NULL, cancellable, callback, user_data);
  g_task_set_source_tag(task, start_data_acq_async);

  g_task_set_return_on_cancel(task, FALSE);

  g_task_set_task_data(task, params, free_data_acq_data);

  // Run the acquisition in a worker thread:
  g_task_run_in_thread(task, data_acq_cb);

  g_object_unref(task);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  
  // ... build/show ui ...
  GtkWidget *progressBar;
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  // ...

  progressBar = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "progress_bar"));
  GCancellable *cancellable; 
 
  struct dataAcqParams *params = g_malloc(sizeof(*params));

  params->progressBar = progressBar;
  params->cancellable = cancellable;
  params->timeoutID = gdk_threads_add_timeout(100, progressBar_timeout_cb,
                                        params);

  start_data_acq_async(params, cancellable, NULL, NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access the progress bar pointer from the UI thread, then I would suggest not freeing it in the worker thread. Maybe when the task completes or is cancelled, you could use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` to queue up another function that will free the resources used on the UI side like `dataAcqParams`, instead of freeing it in the worker thread?

Comment: To make sure I understand what you're suggesting, this basically removes the functionality of the `GTask` automatically freeing memory as I handle it myself by manually freeing it either at the end of the computation or when it gets cancelled? I believe that will work.

Comment: That's right; if you can't guarantee that GTask will free the memory in the thread that "owns" it, then you should free it manually.